# Unique entries in HashSet<List<T>> where list might have null entries

Tags: java, null, hashset

There is a `List<MyElement> = new ArrayList<MyElement>();`

```
class MyElement {
  private Object[] values;
  //...
}
```

I need to find all unique entries in this List. I would use `HashSet`, BUT the problem is that `values` may contain `null` **AND** it should be assumed that `null` is equal to any other value. For instance, `Object[] o1 = new Object[]{1,null,"s2"}` and `Object[] o2 = new Object[]{1,2,"s2"}` should be considered as the same entries (i.e. non-unique), and only one of them should be kept in the `HashSet`. Is there any way to override proper functions in HashSet?

Comment: I editted the title, I think it describes better what you are after, feel free to rollback or re-edit if you think I am wrong.

Comment: One thing: do the _order_ of the values matter? (If it doesn't, `{1,"s2",null}` would be equal to `{2,1,"s2"}`)

Comment: What should the result be if you have {1}, {2} and {null} ? In particular, if you insert 1 and then 2 the elements are clearly different, but if you insert the null wildcard, they become equal, and the set should shrink by one element ?

Comment: Take `o3 = new Object[]{1, 3, "s2"}`. Which one of o1 and o2 should be kept? If you keep o2, o3 will also be kept, if you keep o1, o2 and o3 will be discarded. You need some additional logic (ie. keep ones with least null's)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need the O(1) time for add() and contains() ? I can not see a good way to write a hashCode() function for your MyElement class that would satisfy your requirements.

A Comparator (or making MyElement Comparable) however could do the trick, and you could then use a TreeSet to find out the unique elements of your list.

Here is a first attempt (you shouldn't use it as-is, it probably won't work).

```
class MyElementComparator implements Comparator<MyElement> {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyElement e, MyElement f) {
        int sizeCmp = e.values.length - f.values.length;

        if(sizeCmp != 0) // Lists are of different sizes, elements aren't equal
            return sizeCmp; 

        // Start comparing element by element
        for(int i=0; i<e.values.length; i++) {
            Object eo = e.values[i];
            Object fo = f.values[i];

            // Null is a wildcard
            if(eo == null || fo == null)
                continue;

            // If objects are the same, then continue too.
            if(eo == fo || eo.equals(fo))
                continue;

            // Otherwise, decide on one object or the other based on hashcode (or any other valid mean).
                return eo.hashCode() - fo.hashCode();
        }

        // All elements were equal or skipped, then the objects are equal.
        return 0;
    }
}
```

A quick tests seems to indicate it works:

```
    MyElement a = new MyElement(1, null, "s2");
    MyElement b = new MyElement(1, 2, "s2");
    MyElement c = new MyElement(null, "s", 3);

    TreeSet<MyElement> set = new TreeSet<MyElement>(new MyElementComparator());
    set.add(a);
    set.add(b);
    set.add(c);
    System.out.println(set.size()); // 2
```

But the thing will fail if you add to the set an element that is equal to two other elements that are different. For example {1} and {2} are different, but if you add {null}, then the set should be reduced to {null} and this won't happen.

No Comparator will achieve that, you will need another data structure, maybe a Disjoint set (Union Find) ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

Comment: It won't work, standard collections require transitive equivalence.

Comment: Isn't this relation transitive ?

Comment: `(a, b, c)` == `(a, null, c)` == `(a, x, c)`, but `(a, b, c)` != `(a, x, c)` - not transitive

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that null references should not be equals to anything, as the [equals contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) states:

> *For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.*

So if your `values` field is meaningful for your `equals` implementation, then you cannot implement what you say without breaking the contract.

I'd replace the `Object[]` field for a `List` one, and implement equals in the `MyElement` class. This will in turn provide a meaningful equals for the list, [as its contract states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29). Of course if you override equals, you should override hashcode as well to keep the thing consistent.

I'd leave the good old `HashSet` untouched, keep in mind that writting correct collections is not a trivial task, no matter how easy it can seem at first glance. So override your `MyElement` hashcode and equals methods to fit your needs without breaking both contracts.